# Calculate a triangular crystal

Tags: java, math, geometry

A **regularly-triangular 2D crystal** can be conceived of as being built up by a stacking of microscopic regularly-triangular units, as show here:

[image]

What's the correct method to calculate the total number of triangles of such a 4x4 crystal in Java?

```
var a; (even) 
var b; (odd)
```

Comment: What sort of input are you given? Vertexes? What have you started with code wise? You've asked a very broad question (and most likely a homework one) which the community will be reluctant to solve, but willing to help.

Comment: Also, are your crystals 2D or 3D?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I'm just looking for the calculation.

Comment: Okay, still, what input are you given? Are these things really completely regular (made of congruent equilateral triangles) ?

Comment: I think I understand but I'm still wondering what a and b represent in your question.

Comment: I'm assuming the "mathematica" tag was accidental.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way of systematically finding a solution to your problem:

You are given the number of triangles that you find on each side of your crystal, say `n`. Now, let the crystal rest on one side like in the image you have shown to us and attach a number to each row of triangles, your first row will have number `1` and so on.

Now look at row `2`, for example. It has 2 upward-pointing triangles and one downward-pointing triangle.

Can you generalise this? How many upward-pointing triangles are there in row `n`? How many downward-pointing ones?

If you have the answer to that question, you can sum the numbers for the individual rows in code - or come up with a nice closed formula for the sum.

---

Okay - I couldn't resist. The following picture gives such a nice way of thinking about the problem that it practically solves itself. You look at it and realize that your problem actually reduces to counting squares (which is easy of course). It is similar in spirit to the solution suggested by @femtoRgon, but you don't even have to think about areas!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the little triangles only its n + 2((n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1) which you get by looking at the pattern of triangles facing one way and facing the opposite way.

Look at it another way and you can see its count(n) = (2n-1) + count(n-1) for n>1 and count(n) 1 for n=1 since each large triangle just adds another layer of triangles interleaved along one side.

If you need the 1x1x1 triangles and the 2x2x2 triangles up to the nxnxn triangle, its more complicated but pretty simple algebra.

Comment: Another answer reminds me that a perfect square is the sum of consecutive odd integers. So 3^2 = 9 = 1 + 3 + 5. So the recursive solution above would be equivalent to his solution only more computing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct calculation for the number of triangles as represented, in a X by X triangle is:

```
X*X
```

My reasoning:  Such a triangle is 1/2 the area of the corresponding X by X square, and each unit triangle is 1/2 the area of the unit square.  We can determine the number of unit squares in the larger square with `S = X*X` (S for the area of the square), so we can calculate the number f triangles:  `T = S/2 = (X*X)/2` (T for the area of the triangle), and since two of our unit triangle have the same area as 1 unit square, twice the area is the number of triangles, or `num_triangles = (X*X)/2 * 2 = X*X`